# How to clone a jQuery object and its children, without references in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, object, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to clone a jQuery object, its children, and no references. My understanding is that `clone()` should accomplish this, but in IE11, the second time I try to append one of the child objects to the blank surrounding div, that child object no longer exists. You can see this by clicking "click me" twice in my snippet, using IE11.

I think my problem may be that the child references were cloned, so the blank div overwrote them, but may be wrong about this. So far, `clone()` has worked the best for cloning the parent element. I prefer to use jQuery rather than `getElementsByClassName`. I did not have luck using `$.extend(true, {}, $('.allItems'));`

I would appreciate any help with this!

```js
window.$allItems = $('.carousel_item').clone();

$('.link').on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  $('.blue').html('').append('<div id="bills"></div>');
  $('#bills').append($allItems[0]);
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: #d0e4f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">clickme</a>
<div class="blue">
  <div id="bills">
    <div class='carousel_item'>
      <img src='http://fillmurray.com/150/200'>
      <div>
        <span>Tomatoes</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='carousel_item'>
      <img src='http://fillmurray.com/200/200'>
      <div>
        <span>Film</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the point of your code, like, what are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to duplicate carousel_items?

Comment: @chiliNUT this code is a simplified version. in the original, there are many more divs with images and data. Clicking a particular link will show a filtered selection of those divs.

Comment: if you execute this same snippet on Chrome, you'll see the desired behavior: the first click filters to only the `[0]`th item, and all subsequent clicks just display that item again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.

To append the carousel item more than once after appending a blank div, I needed to clone the DOM elements each time the function was called. I needed to add one line to the click listener:

`$allItems = $allItems.clone();`